# Warnings and Errors in AOT compilation

Tags: angular, aot, ngx-charts

I'm having some warnings and errors in AOT mode, it's OK in JIT mode.

In AOT mode the application works fine in browser but I'm having warning and error messages during building, like this:

For example the first warning:

```
WARNING in ./~/@swimlane/ngx-charts/release/ngx-charts.module.js
Cannot find source file '../build/ngx-charts.module.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../build/ngx-charts.module.ts' in '/Users/guest/Prive/DevAngular/proto-chartev3-angular/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-charts/release'
 @ ./aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts 60:0-70
 @ ./src/main-aot.ts
 @ multi ./src/main-aot
```

For example the first error:

```
ERROR in ./~/@swimlane/ngx-charts/release/common/base-chart.component.css
    Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin, refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example
        at Object.module.exports.pitch (/Users/guest/Prive/DevAngular/proto-chartev3-angular/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js:27:9)
```

ngx-charts version:6.0.1

Angular version: 4.2.4

Webpack version: 2.2.1

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am seeing similar warnings using @angular/cli@8 with an AOT build specifically with ngx-charts and ngx-cookie-service packages. The app still works fine however it seems source maps are not linked in the browser for these packages. I have been trying to exclude these packages from being processed by the source-map-loader but haven't had any success yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a problem with your webpack configuration. I have solved the extract-text-webpack-plugin error the following:

```
// css loader for app styles
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } },
        ],
      }),
    },
    // css loader for node_modules to prevent nasty warnings
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'src/frontend'),
      use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    },
```

To get all styles from node_modules you need to import them somewhere in your styles.ts:

```
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-charts/release/index.css';
```